# Get path of inserted usb in dbus

Tags: python, path, usb, detect, dbus

I'm writing a program in python using dbus that detects inserted usb drives and manipulates the files inside of them. However, I can't seem to retrieve the path on my system of an inserted usb. Is there someway that I can get the path of an inserted usb in dbus, perhaps by using the GetProperty() method? I have tried using GetProperty("block.device"), but that returns /dev/sdc1 which doesn't exist on my system. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do any of these questions help?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+usb+detect  This is a pretty common question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "NativePath" Property.

Here is an example of getting the property (using C# not python)
https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/udisk-sharp/src/1a4d3e031fa1/src/test/Main.cs